# Makefile - use other value if command doesn't produce desired output

Tags: makefile

So, in my Makefile I export a variable:

Makefile

```
export my_var = $(shell my_command)

test:
  command $(my_var)
```

However, my problem is that some has the `my_command` and some of them doesn't get desired output (because of permissions), and others doesn't have it at all, which is desired.
So, what I want is to be able to have an conditional to set a value if `my_var` is not desired, e.g:

PSEUDO

```
export my_var = $(shell my_command)
ifdef my_var != DESIRED_VALUE
  my_var = "desired value1"
else
  my_var = "desired value2"
endif

...
```

Comment: If it's just a matter of `my_command` existing or not, you can handle this in your shell expression: `export my_var = $(shell my_command || echo "desired value")`

Comment: Sorry @larsks, I've updated question.

Comment: I don't think it's an improvement; now we have to guess what `SOMETHING SOMETHING` stands for.

Comment: Take a look at the Make manual section on [conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html).

Comment: @tripleee, Idk what to put there, SOMETHING is basically nothing, I dont know how to write my `ifdef`.

Comment: Some things are better done via a pre-build configuration script.  There's no hard rule for where it's better to do the job before `make` and when to do it in `make`, but personally, I'd put what you describe on the before `make` side.

Comment: Also, we could better evaluate both the timing and the implementation if you said more specifically what you want to achieve.  That is, what is the larger objective here? I suspect this may be an X-Y question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `ifdef`, which is for **if** something is **def**ined. If you want `ifeq` or `ifneq` (documented in the [manual to which I linked in my comment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html)), which is for testing if two values are equal (or not). So you could do something like:

```
my_var = $(shell echo unexpected value)

ifneq ($(my_var), desired value 1)
my_var = desired value 2
endif

test:
    echo $(my_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to run command at makefile parse time (before any recipes are run), you would do something like:

```
ifeq ($(shell my_command),DESIRED_VALUE)
    my_var = "desired value2"
else
    my_var = "desired value1"
fi
```

or

```
my_var := $(if $(filter $(shell my_command),DESIRED_VALUE),desired value2,desired_value1)
```

(Note the `:=` in the second example, as you would likely want [immediate expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#:%7E:text=We%20say%20that%20expansion%20is,if%20it%20is%20not%20immediate.) for this...)

You can also do this at recipe exec:

```
test:
    @my_bash_var="$(if $(filter $(shell my_command),DESIRED_VALUE),desired value2,desired_value1)"; \
    echo "$$(my_bash_var)"
```

This would be necessary if `mycommand` is generated, or is dependent on a generated artifact, from another recipe.   (In this case, note the `\` to concatenate the recipe lines and the `$$`, as `my_bash_var` is a bash variable instead of a makefile variable).